# Show only checked products

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, sql-order-by

I am developing a Meal Ordering System where Customers can order all the items in the menu that is managed by the Administrator.

Currently in my system, all the items that is added by the Admin is automatically added on the store that is seen by the customers using this code.

```
<?php
            require "connect.php";
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM internet_shop");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo '<a rel="facebox" href="orderpage.php?id='.$row['id'].'&trnasnum='.$transnum.'"><img src="img/products/'.$row['img'].'" alt="'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).'" width="210" class="pngfix" style="padding:5px 8px; " /></a>';
            }

            ?>
```

This is the code for the Admin to add items.

```
<?php
include('../store/connect.php');

    if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "";
    }else{
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size= getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

        if ($image_size==FALSE) {

            echo "That's not an image!";

        }else{

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../store/img/products/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

            $location=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
            $type=$_POST['type'];
            $rate=$_POST['rate'];
            $desc=$_POST['desc'];

            $update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO internet_shop (name, price, description, img)
            VALUES
            ('$type','$rate','$desc','$location')");
            header("location: products.php");
            exit();
            }
    }
?>
```

Now what I want is to add a checkbox beside all the items that is added by the Admin. That checkbox will control the items that will be shown on the store that the Customers can view. I want to remove the showing of added items automatically and let the checkbox control what to show and what not.

Comment: add a column in the database that will be your check point if it can be shown or not. If you need to show or hide the item just update the value

Comment: Thank you! Now that is for the database side. What about in the coding?

Comment: in your select add a where clause e.g. `"SELECT * FROM internet_shop where Show_Item = 'yes'"` `no`  when you dont want to show the item

Comment: So when checkbox is checked it will automatically update the value of Show_Item to yes?

Comment: you can have it from the start during insert and also in update. its up to you the important thing is you have those values to determine the status of the item to be shown of hidden